# creating pipeline for dictvectorizer and linearsvc in sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I trained a LinearSVC classifier with a NER dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/abhinavwalia95/entity-annotated-corpus) and would like for it to be able to predict new data. From what I have read I need to create and save the model as a pipeline to do this. I have been trying to do this based on other examples on SO but can't get it to work. How can I turn my existing model into a pipelined version?

The first code snippet saves, and the second is one of my attempts at making it into the pipeline but I get an 'str' object has no attribute 'items' error. I think it has to do with the to_dict process but don't know how to replicate this in a pipelined version, can anyone help.

```
dframe = pd.read_csv("ner.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False)
dframe.dropna(inplace=True)
dframe[dframe.isnull().any(axis=1)].size 
x_df = dframe.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'sentence_idx', 'tag'], axis=1)

vectorizer = DictVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_df.to_dict("records"))
y = dframe.tag.values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

model = LinearSVC(loss="squared_hinge",C=0.5,class_weight='balanced',multi_class='ovr')
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
dump(model, 'filename.joblib')
```

```
dframe = pd.read_csv("ner.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False)
dframe.dropna(inplace=True)
dframe[dframe.isnull().any(axis=1)].size 
x_df = dframe.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'sentence_idx', 'tag'], axis=1)
y = dframe.tag.values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_df, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

pipe = Pipeline([('vectorizer', DictVectorizer(x_df.to_dict("records"))), ('model', LinearSVC)]) 

pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Why don't you dump the pipeline itself directly, that would be way better for the production?

Comment: In order to predict with your model, you don't need a pipeline. You already trained your model with model.fit(x_train,y_train). Now you can just use model.predict() to make predictions for new data. Have a look at this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.predict

Comment: yes I can predict on the same data set, but when I try to predict new data and use dictvectorizer the featureset is different to the model and gives error. this is why I think I need pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to adjust your second part like this:

```
dframe = pd.read_csv("ner.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False)
dframe.dropna(inplace=True)
dframe[dframe.isnull().any(axis=1)].size 
x_df = dframe.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'sentence_idx', 'tag'], axis=1)
y = dframe.tag.values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_df.to_dict("records"), y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

pipe = Pipeline([('vectorizer', DictVectorizer()), ('model', LinearSVC(loss="squared_hinge",C=0.5,class_weight='balanced',multi_class='ovr'))]) 

pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

You were trying to pass your `DictVectorizer()` your data in the parameters by using

> DictVectorizer(x_df.to_dict("records"))

but that does not work. The only available parameters for the DictVectorizer can be found here in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html).

And the second mistake was that you tried to fit your DictVectorizer() in the pipeline with the data from x_df with

> pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)

The problem here is that the x_train data will be given to your `DictVectorizer()`, but x_train is just the split x_df and earlier in your code without the pipeline, you provided the D`ictVectorizer()` with the data in form of `x_df.to_dict("records")`.

So you need to pass the same type of data also with your pipeline. Thats why I already split the `x_df.to_dict("records")` with the `train_test_split()` in the adjusted code, so that the vectorizer can process it.

Last thing is that you also forgot the brackets when defining your pipeline for the `LinearSVC()`

> ('model', LinearSVC)